# Problem downloading quarkus-mongodb-client dependencies

Tags: mongodb, quarkus

I am trying QUARKUS - USING THE MONGODB CLIENT from https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb

I am on a centos 7 host. Cannot compile apparently failing to download quarkus-mongodb-client dependencies.

The compile is stuck here ...

```
QVDUN1CLGA0055> ./mvnw compile quarkus:dev
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< org.acme:mongodb-quickstart >---------------------
[INFO] Building mongodb-quickstart 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.mongodb:bson:jar:3.12.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.mongodb:bson:jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mongodb-quickstart ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ mongodb-quickstart ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.4.2.Final:dev (default-cli) @ mongodb-quickstart ---
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Downloading from central: http://central/org/mongodb/bson/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: http://central/org/mongodb/bson/3.10.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: http://central/org/mongodb/bson/3.11.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from nexus: http://ud-bam2.apps.dev.det.nsw.edu.au:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/mongodb/bson/3.12.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: http://central/org/mongodb/bson/3.12.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: http://central/org/mongodb/bson/3.12.2-SNAPSHOT/bson-3.12.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
Downloading from nexus: http://ud-bam2.apps.dev.det.nsw.edu.au:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/mongodb/bson/3.12.2-SNAPSHOT/bson-3.12.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
Downloading from central: http://central/org/mongodb/bson/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from nexus: http://ud-bam2.apps.dev.det.nsw.edu.au:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/mongodb/bson/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: http://central/org/mongodb/bson/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT/bson-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
Downloading from nexus: http://ud-bam2.apps.dev.det.nsw.edu.au:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/mongodb/bson/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT/bson-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
Downloading from central: http://central/org/mongodb/bson/4.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: http://central/org/mongodb/bson/4.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: http://central/org/mongodb/bson/4.0.4-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: http://central/org/mongodb/bson/4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
```

I have tried adding the dependency on another simple java project, it only downloads if I add the version 1.4.2.Final on that java project.

But adding the version on the quarkus did not help either.

From the warnings it looks like the dependencies might be missing.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at Maven Central, both dependencies are there:

- bson 3.12.2 [is here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mongodb/bson/3.12.2/jar)
- bson 4.0.0 [is here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mongodb/bson/4.0.0/jar)

However, you're not downloading from Maven Central, but from two custom Maven repositories (http://central is the one, the other is http://ud-bam2.apps.dev.det.nsw.edu.au:8081/nexus/). You or your colleagues need to make sure that those repositories either properly mirror Maven Central or that they contain the resources you need.

If you're allowed to, you might add https://search.maven.org/ as repository in your `~/.m2/settings.xml` file.

Comment: **Thanks for the help. This resolved the issue. Also added the profile containing this repository to the active profile.**

Now getting other issues. Few Warnings like:

    <code>[WARNING] Could not validate integrity of download from 
    https://search.maven.org/org/mongodb/mongodb-crypt/1.0.0/mongodb-crypt-1.0.0.jar: 
    Checksum validation failed, .

and

    [WARNING] The POM for org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:jar:4.0.0 is invalid, 
    transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, .

compile is stuck at:

    Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005

Comment: Well, the checksum for the mongodb-crypt seem okay. Could check the pom.xml for mongoldb-driver-sync? Is it really invalid XML?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, there was an issue in our BOM, we should have fixed the bson version as some of our dependencies use a version range. This can sometimes cause issues and is suboptimal.

I created https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/9207 to fix this issue once and for all.